# Is there a unit-testable way to upload files to ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: c#, file-upload, tdd, asp.net-web-api

I'm working in a project that uses the new ASP.NET WebAPI. My current task is to accept an uploaded file. So far, I have used TDD to drive out the WebAPI code, but I've hit a wall with uploading. I'm currently following the advice found at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2, but there seems to be no way at all to drive this out of a unit test. In order to get at the file and form data, I have to use `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`, which is impossible to mock and/or override. Short of forsaking my TDD approach, what can I do?

Here's the code from the example:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
{
    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

    // Read the form data and return an async task.
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
            }

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        });

    return task;
}
```

The first problem is this line:

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
```

For starters, to unit test this code, I need to be able to inject such a provider. It does WAY too much in that simple constructor call to be "newing it up" in line. There's got to be another way. (If not, WebAPI fails)

Comment: can you provide some code that you are using..? nothing is impossible by the way..

Comment: Will this link help you http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Comment: What piece of the upload process are you trying to test? The controller? Or the code that saves the file?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, that's the link that I included in my question.

Comment: @Matt Phillips, I would like to test both separately. I extracted what I could out to an UploadHandler class, but the stream provider is a big problem.

Comment: A more recent, straightforward answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27961019/264628

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is "no". ASP.NET is an inheritance-based framework. If you're trying to write composition-based applications, you will, at some point, find friction and road-blocks. Time to switch to something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org).

Comment: added answer above, would like to know your thoughts

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted since there was no comment. The version of webapi that was being used at the time of this question did NOT have a way to "unit test" the upload of a file. Testing was marginally possible, but with a lot of extra plumbing code and only produced an "integration test", not a unit test.

Answer (score 3):

I abstracted out a provider wrapper so I could mock those moving parts, something like

```
    public interface IMultiPartFormDataStreamProviderWrapper : IDependency
    {
        string LocalFileName { get; }
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider Provider { get; }
    }

    public class MultiPartFormDataStreamProviderWrapper : IMultiPartFormDataStreamProviderWrapper
    {
        public const string UploadPath = "~/Media/Default/Vocabulary/";
        private MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider;

        public MultiPartFormDataStreamProviderWrapper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(httpContextAccessor.Current().Server.MapPath(UploadPath));
        }

        public string LocalFileName
        {
            get { return provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName; }
        }


        public MultipartFormDataStreamProvider Provider
        {
            get { return provider; }
        }
    }
```

So I could then do something like

```
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider.Provider).ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                        if (t.IsCanceled || t.IsFaulted)
                            return (object)new { success = false };
```

Not ideal, but gives some piece of mind. What do you think?

Comment: Can you unpack this a bit? It doesn't even compile as posted.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't thrown in the towel on Web API yet, you might try [System.Net.Http.TestableMultipartStreamProviders](https://github.com/ladenedge/TestableMultipartStreamProviders), which are a drop-in rewrite of the Microsoft stream providers.  Their benefit is that they rely on [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/) for file operations, which means the file operations can be mocked in unit tests.  The [wiki](https://github.com/ladenedge/TestableMultipartStreamProviders/wiki) gives some ideas about leveraging DI to make testing controllers less of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [self-hosting](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-Self-Host-30abca12) capability, you can write a unit test that:

- Starts up the controllers (and various other formatters/filters/etc.)
- Uses an HttpClient (or personally, I would use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)) to submit a file to that controller (with RestSharp, you can use the `AddFile` function to do this)
- Validates the input stream however you would like (e.g. by overriding the provider or just inspecting the value that is passed to a test controller or something)

Comment: I wrote a blog post about using WebAPI self hosting capability in a test fixture http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/self-hosting-web-service-inside-test.html

Comment: self-hosting testing is really integration testing, not unit testing; if you can't at least mock the file system you're not unit testing