# unit test for WebAPI that upload files from ajax

Tags: unit-testing, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I need to import a content of a csv file to my db. I used [this tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm) 
to upload the file with ajax, save it on the local server, read it, insert items to DB and delete the file from server.

Now I want to test it with unit test. How can I test the "Post" function? How can I "upload" a csv file for it?

Comment: As @m.edmonson says you would have to stub the external entities and just test the logic associated with the Post action. If you touch any external dependencies such as File System within your test, it is not a Unit Test. It is an Integration test.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064653/is-there-a-unit-testable-way-to-upload-files-to-asp-net-webapi ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an integration test rather than a unit test. Unit tests do not test between systems (such as when uploading files) only small pieces of distinct logic on the same system.

Take a look at [integration testing on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) for more details.

In addition I would highly recommend writing your tests *first* before implementing any logic.